# Develop multiple apps from same code base in android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, xcode, android-studio

Is there a way by which i can just import the images and the data into an existing project and generate a new app. I have found two solutions in iOS for this :

1. Using multiple targets .
2. I also had the idea of web app but the only apps which act as a wrapper have been rejected by Apple.

Now my question is if there is any other workaround which can be achieved for both iOS and Android ?

Comment: @ sigkill : Make library project for reusable components :)

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have looked into PhoneGap and Xamarin?